# Couldn't install package, project targets Framework without assembly references

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget-package

When I try to install Firebase Messaging Nuget package on the solution it gives me this error -

> "Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1021.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

And for the android installation it says

> "Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 42.1021.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.6,Profile=Profile44', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

How do I get it to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the latest stable Xamarin.Forms and have your project's compileSdkVersion (so Target Framework) **set to 7.0** or higher. You will then be able to install newer versions of Android Support and therefore **Google Play Services packages.**

Happy coding!!

Comment: It doesn't let me update the Xamarin.Android.Support packages, it stops at the Compat and says "Install Failed, rolling back" . the framwork is set to 7.1